# How to use Age() in JPA query

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to fetch a column which will show the transaction day difference in **Days** and **Hours** from current timestamp.
I have found many solution on native query.
for example: Age() function works fine but didn't find any expression related to JPA.
 query looks like this
 `select AGE(trans_date) from transaction` 
this query is giving data like this :
 `0 years 0 mons 18 days 9 hours 50 mins 28.126 secs`
 I only need the days and hours and this needs to be a JPA expression.<>
Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Which database you are using ?

Comment: @Eklavya postgres.

Comment: Show the repository also

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to print or transform a timestamp in Java? Or do you want to use the time difference in filtering your records in the JPA query? There are hundreds of questions here on these topics. And you should post the entity definition

Comment: @perissf I need to create a jpa query which will have the difference of transaction date column with today's date time.